# Add parameters to TabBar Storyboard segue

Tags: ios, segue, tabbar

I have a `TabBar` with 3 buttons, the 2nd and 3nd buttons have a segue to the same controller, which should show different info depending on one param.

[image]

I've overridden `TabBar` class to implement.-

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
```

to be able to add my param just before performing the segue, but I must be missing something obvious because `prepareForSegue` is not getting called.

Is there anyway to achieve this without programmatically creating custom segues?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not getting called? That sounds very unusual.

Comment: I did not test this, but maybe overriding tabBar:didSelectItem: in your UITabBarDelegate helps. Your UITabBarDelegate probably is your UITabBarController.

Comment: Could just do it in `viewDidLoad` of your TabBar class instead. Iterate over `viewControllers` and configure them as appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

According to me you cannot interact with segue linked as "root" controllers.
Those segue are not "getting called" as they don't represent a transition between two view controllers.

If you look at Interface Builder there is no settings available for that kind of segue.

I had a similar issue in one of my project and solve the issue by setting the controllers programmatically. After that you add your view controller in storyboard and set a "Storyboard ID" in the right hand panel.

Then, you can instantiate your view controller by doing

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_ID"];
```

And affect them to your UITabBarController by doing

```
[self setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks @foOg, not the solution I was looking for, but I'll keep that in mind as a last resource.

Comment: I am curious if you find a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best practice, but I finally ended up getting the selected tab from my controllers.-

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

This simple way, I know what info should I show, without changing my `storyboard segues`.